# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Below are the columns in the DataFrame of data I am iterating on,

> ```
> > incident_id                            int64 date                     
> > object state                           object city_or_county          
> > object address                         object n_killed                
> > int64 n_injured                        int64 incident_url             
> > object source_url                      object
> > incident_url_fields_missing            bool congressional_district    
> > float64 gun_stolen                     object gun_type               
> > object incident_characteristics        object latitude                
> > float64 location_description           object longitude              
> > float64 n_guns_involved                float64 notes                  
> > object participant_age                 object participant_age_group   
> > object participant_gender              object participant_name        
> > object participant_relationship        object participant_status      
> > object participant_type                object sources                 
> > object state_house_district            float64 state_senate_district  
> > float64 dtype: object
> ```

and below is the code i have written,

```
def count_entries(df,col_name):
    """ Return a dictionary with counts of occurrences as value for each key"""
    cols_count = {}
    col = df[col_name]
    for entry in col:
        if entry in cols_count.keys():
            cols_count[entry] += 1
        else:
            cols_count = 1
    return cols_count
result = count_entries(data, 'gun_stolen')
print (result)
```

Comment: `cols_count = 1`?

Answer (score 3):

```
def count_entries(df,col_name):
    """ Return a dictionary with counts of occurrences as value for each key"""
    cols_count = {}
    col = df[col_name]
    for entry in col:
        if entry in cols_count.keys():
            cols_count[entry] += 1
        else:
            # you forgot the [entry] in else statement.
            cols_count[entry] = 1
    return cols_count
result = count_entries(data, 'gun_stolen')
print (result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'F':list('aaabbc')
})

print (df)
   A  F
0  a  a
1  b  a
2  c  a
3  d  b
4  e  b
5  f  c

def count_entries(df,col_name):
    """ Return a dictionary with counts of occurrences as value for each key"""
    return df[col_name].value_counts().to_dict()
```

Or use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def count_entries(df,col_name):
    """ Return a dictionary with counts of occurrences as value for each key"""
    return dict(Counter(df[col_name]))
```

```
result = count_entries(df, 'F')
print (result)
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```